# gt table save to Word

Tags: r, gt

Currently the `gtsave` function in the `gt` package does not support `MS-Word`. I tried converting a `gt` object to a `flextable` object to then save as word, but flextable doesn't support a gt object. And when I just copy paste an `html` to Word, the aesthetics are lost. And a PNG is not ideal either, as when I resize the picture, the font size does not match the document font size. Is there a workaround this?

```
# Download package    
devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt")
# Load package     
library(gt)    
# Code        
gt_tbl =  gt(head(mtcars), caption = 'This is table caption') %>%
tab_header(title="Some Title", subtitle="Table 1: Mtcars with gt."
# Export the table
# As word
library(flextable)
 gt_tbl %>%
           flextable::as_flextable() %>%
           flextable::save_as_docx(path = "~")
```

Error

```
Error in UseMethod("as_flextable") : 
  no applicable method for 'as_flextable' applied to an object of class "c('gt_tbl', 'list')"
```

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem recently and ended up using `flextable` only to make it work. If you provide some [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example maybe you will get aswers on how to switch from `gt` to `flextable`. Also, maybe check `gtsummary` (that can be used with `flextable` see https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/extensions.html#gtsummary).

Comment: Well my table uses dataframes, so `gtsummary` doesn't serve my purpose.

Comment: Two options: use `flextable` directly instead of `gt`; use my `huxtable` and convert to `flextable`. I'd suggest the former. It supports captions and headers.

Comment: @dash2, does your package has a function similar to `tab_spanner` in `gt`?

Comment: huxtable has `insert_row()` and `merge_cells()` which can do the same thing. flextable has `add_header_row()`.